# How to add tag with value

Tags: pug

I'm interested to know how to add in Pug the tag containing another tag necessary to display a Font Awesome icon and a dynamic value. I tried this way:

```
    p!= "<i class=\"far fa-bell\"></i>"
        if val.i != null
            = " " + val.i
        else
            = " EXAMPLE TEXT"
```

I got this output:

```
<p><i class="fas fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>" 2"</p>
```

I want to add a whitespace between the icon and the following text, but Pug adds the quotes with the output and actually I don't see any result at the web-page. I could add more whitespaces before the value i or example text and nothing changes. Is there any way to beautify the output of the tag i with the text or value following after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid Pug.

I would write it like this, using [piped text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#whitespace-control) to control whitespace:

```
p
  i.far.fa-bell
  |
  |
  if val.i
    | #{val.i}
  else
    | Example Text
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried your code, it's works similar but I didn't know that my code is not valid for Pug. Thank you for clarification. Unfortunately, it doesn't affect the postion of text after the icon, because Pug for some reason doesn't add the whitespaces after the <i> tag. I have attached the output of Pug with an [image](https://imgur.com/a/h8OEQes). I could use CSS to add margin between the icon and the following text but I thought that it's possible to avoid this way.

Comment: In your screenshot there _is_ a space after the `<i>` tag. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, there is one whitespace, but I would like to try two whitespaces or more, because the icon and text are too close to each other.

Comment: Then you'll need to use CSS or non-breaking spaces. HTML [collapses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace) multiple spaces into one by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have supposed that it's necessary to use CSS for that.